# Django-Nginx Patch request :405 Method \"METHOD_OTHER\" not allowed

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework.

Patch on api endpoint( users/*user_id*) is working in local django server on my machine. But on nginx development server its showing

> {"detail":"Method \"METHOD_OTHER\" not allowed."}

Do we need to change some settings in nginx?

Comment: Can you share the nginx config? Also if possible a sample snippet.

Comment: What is the request header and the full nginx error message?

Comment: have you tried without underscore (according to the RFC underscore is permitted, but it may be something in nginx parser...) (latest nginx is allowing such methods it has rule:  if (ch < 'A' || ch > 'Z') && ch != '_') {return NGX_HTTP_PARSE_INVALID_METHOD;}

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried the access the same code from different network and it worked.
Probably it was firewall issue of that particular wifi network.